# How to display data with pagaination on backend?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages, pagination, wp-list-pages

I am new with WordPress development so I have no idea how to do this functionality with WordPress.

I got one task to display some data from database and have to display records with pagination(Just like WordPress is using), View, Edit and Trash.

[image]

I want to list all data just like above image and all similar functionality I wonting.

I really thankful If you guide me how to do this as I have no idea with WordPress.

Thanks.

Comment: Not related to WordPress. Just [have a look around](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+pagination).

Comment: What do you mean not related with WordPress question. I know how to create pagination all things but I have to implement with `WordPress`. I have also attached screenshot with my question and that I want inside WordPress backend. If you know how to do that then suggest posts/articles.

Comment: I got you that you need a pagination like WP Admin Post List. You said: *I got one task to display some data from database* - where's your code then?

Comment: Voting too broad as just the trash functionality might be a huge project depending on what you actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm not going to close this one. Yes, there are things missing (like **code** and what was tried already), but there is room for improvement and it's on topic. @Avenger Please [edit] your question, show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Hint: Take a look at the [`WP_List_Table` docs in Codex as starter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table).